# Expand the function $f(z) = \frac{1+2z^2}{z^2+z^4} $ into power series of $z$ in all areas of convergence.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, power-series

I'm studying for my upcoming complex analysis qualifying exam by working through problems in past exams. For this problem, I'd like to know (1) if my answer is correct and complete (i.e. whether I've made any errors/omissions), and (2) if there are any better ways of doing this. I'm specifically curious about whether or not there are other areas of convergence that I need to address. Thanks!

**Question:**

Expand the function
$$
f(z) = \frac{1+2z^2}{z^2+z^4}
$$
into power series of $z$ in all areas of convergence.

**Attempted Solution:**

We begin by noting that this function has poles at $z=0$ and $z=\pm i$. Then we proceed by recalling the geometric series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k = \frac{1}{1-z},
$$
which converges for $|z|<1$. Using this form, we can rewrite $f(z)$ as follows

\begin{align*}
f(z) &= \frac{1+2z^2}{z^2+z^4} \\
&= \frac{1}{z^2+z^4} + \frac{2z^2}{z^2+z^4} \\
&= \frac{1}{z^2(1-(-z^2))} + \frac{2z^2}{z^2(1-(-z^2))} \\ 
&= \frac{1}{z^2}\left(\frac{1}{1-(-z^2)}\right) + 2\left(\frac{1}{1-(-z^2)}\right)\\
&= \left(\frac{1}{z^2}+2\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-(-z^2)}\right)\\
&= \left(\frac{1}{z^2}+2\right) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-z^2)^k \\
&=  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(z^{-2}+2\right)(-1)^k z^{2k}
\end{align*}

for $0<|z|<1$, since there is a pole at $z=0$.

Comment: From the way it is stated, I guess this is one of two parts to the solution.  You also need a different  series valid in $1<|z|$.

Comment: @GEdgar I wondered about that. How would I go about this though?

Comment: If $|z|>1$,  what is the geometric series with sum $1/(z^2+z^4)$ ?

Comment: @GEdgar I'm sorry, I'm unclear what you're asking. I thought that with $|z|>1$, the series would simply diverge?

Comment: I assumed that in saying "all areas" you wanted also $|z|>1$.  This will be a series with negative powers of $z$.  Even your solution has $z^{-2}$ in it.

Comment: @Serafina: Note your series expansion is not correct, since it contains terms with a negative exponent of $z$. So, it is a Laurent series expansion, not a power series expansion. As we have a (double) pole at $z=0$, which is a singularity, a power series expansion at $z=0$ is not feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we are looking for a *[power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series)* we are looking for a representation
\begin{align*}
f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\left(z-z_0\right)^k
\end{align*}
evaluated at center $z_0$.

> We start with a partial fraction decomposition
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f(z)}&=\frac{1+2z^2}{z^2\left(1+z^2\right)}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{i}{2}\,\frac{1}{z+i}-\frac{i}{2}\,\frac{1}{z-i}}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

We have poles at $0$ and $\pm i$. So we can expand each of the terms at $z_0\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,\pm i\}$ in a power series. We obtain

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z^2}&=\frac{1}{\left(z-z_0+z_0\right)^2}=\frac{1}{z_0^2}\,\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{z-z_0}{z_0}\right)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{z_0^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k(k+1)\left(\frac{z-z_0}{z_0}\right)^k\qquad\qquad |z-z_0|<|z_0|\tag{2.1}
\\
\frac{i}{2}\,\frac{1}{z+i}&=\frac{i}{2}\,\frac{1}{(z-z_0)+(z_0+i)}\\
&=\frac{i}{2}\,\frac{1}{z_0+i}\,\frac{1}{1+\frac{z-z_0}{z_0+i}}\\
&=\frac{i}{2}\,\frac{1}{z_0+i}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left(\frac{z-z_0}{z_0+i}\right)^k\qquad\qquad |z-z_0|<|z_0+i|\tag{2.2}
\\
\frac{i}{2}\,\frac{1}{z-i}&=\frac{i}{2}\,\frac{1}{(z-z_0)+(z_0-i)}\\
&=\frac{i}{2}\,\frac{1}{z_0-i}\,\frac{1}{1+\frac{z-z_0}{z_0-i}}\\
&=\frac{i}{2}\,\frac{1}{z_0-i}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left(\frac{z-z_0}{z_0-i}\right)^k\qquad\qquad |z-z_0|<|z_0-i|\tag{2.3}
\end{align*}

> Putting (1) and (2.1) to (2.3) together we conclude $f(z)$ admits the power series representation
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{f(z)}&=\frac{1+2z^2}{z^2\left(1+z^2\right)}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left(\frac{k+1}{z_0^{k+2}}+\frac{i}{2}\frac{1}{(z_0+i)^{k+1}}
> -\frac{i}{2}\frac{1}{(z_0-i)^{k+1}}\right)\left(z-z_0\right)^k}\\
> \end{align*}
> evaluated at $z_0\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,\pm i\}$ and convergent in
> \begin{align*}
> \{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z-z_0|<|z_0| \text{ and } |z-z_0|<|z_0+i| \text{ and } |z-z_0|<|z_0-i|\}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Wow, it seems I had a lot of misunderstanding around this one. It took me a bit to walk through and understand your solution above, but it's making sense now. Thank you. So the way that I did the problem would only apply if the question was asking for a Laurent series, is that correct?

Comment: I think it's a bit confusing to understand the distinction between what is or is not a power series. In some places, a Laurent series is said to be a power series with negative exponents and a Taylor series is said to be a power series with no negative exponents. This makes it seem as though a Laurent series in indeed considered a power series?

Comment: @Serafina: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is useful and was stimulating for some recherche. :-)

Comment: @Serafina: ... and yes, the notion of power series is not always that clear. Nevertheless the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series) stated in Wiki is the common one. We typically use the term *Laurent series* whenever we talk about (generalized) power series with negative exponents of the variable $z$. Similarly we use the term *[Puiseux series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series)* when we want to address (generalized) power series with fractional exponents.

Comment: I'm revisiting this problem and realizing that I'm kind of stuck on how you got the series for $\frac{1}{z^2}$. How did you get from $\frac{1}{(1+\alpha)^2}$ to the summation? ($\alpha = \frac{z-z_0}{z_0}$). At first glance, I thought it was just the geometric series, but I don't know how you got from the squared term to the $(k+1)$ in the summation. Can you please help?

Comment: @Serafina: It's the *binomial* series expansion. We have the coefficient $\binom{-2}{k}=\binom{2+k-1}{k}(-1)^k=\binom{k+1}{1}(-1)^k=(k+1)(-1)^k$.

Comment: Ok, only two more questions on this one (I hope). (1) Shouldn't there be $(-1)^k$ for the final summations in both 2.2 and 2.3 to handle the needed negative sign in the geometric series is $\frac{1}{1-\alpha} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha^k$. A minor point... but I'd like to be sure I'm not missing something. And (2) why can you combine them all into one final summation when the area of convergence is different for each term? Wouldn't you need to somehow combine all of the areas to be the most restricted one or something like that?

Comment: @Serafina: Yes, thanks. Good review, typo corrected. The region of convergence is the *intersection* of the single regions, so that it is admissible to combine them all.

Comment: Awesome, makes sense... thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's perfect. Note that you can even simplifie more your expression:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(z^{-2}+2\right)(-1)^k z^{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kz^{2(k-1)}+2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kz^{2k}=\\\sum_{k=-1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}z^{2k}+2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kz^{2k}\\=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}z^{2k}+2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kz^{2k}=\frac{1}{z^2}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kz^{2k}+2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kz^{2k}\\=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kx^{2k}=\frac{1}{z^2}+1-z^2+z^4+O(z^6)$$
Note that the residue of $f$ in $z=0$ since $a_{-1}=0$

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see how it could be further simplified. That's helpful!

Comment: One quick question... In your further simplification, did the 2 multiplied by the second summation term get lost somewhere by mistake or am I missing something?

Comment: i will edit it to clarify :)

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Oops. Thanks again!